# Constraint layout stacks at the top when using scrollview

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-scrollview

I have been trying to make an application for a school but I ran into some problems. I am trying to make the User Details page scrollable but the constraint layout stacks up at the top:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#9F9F9F">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="@drawable/user_bg"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/userprofile"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:background="@drawable/no_profile_pic"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.27"
            android:contentDescription="User Profile" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userprofilename"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Loading..."
            android:text="Loading..."
            android:textSize="17sp"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.45"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/background"
            android:layout_width="380dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.52" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_image"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_profile"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/background"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/background"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/background"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/background" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Loding..."
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/background"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/background"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/background"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/background"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/bg2"
            android:layout_width="380dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.63" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_class"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_class_24"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.52"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bg2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/bg2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/bg2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bg2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userclass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Loding..."
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.52"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bg2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/bg2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/bg2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bg2"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/bg3"
            android:layout_width="380dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.74" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_dob"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_birthday"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.52"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bg3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/bg3"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/bg3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bg3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userdob"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Loding..."
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.52"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bg3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/bg3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/bg3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bg3"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/bg4"
            android:layout_width="380dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.85" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_num"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_mobile"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.52"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bg4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/bg2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/bg4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bg4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/usernum"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Loading..."
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.52"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bg4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/bg4"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/bg4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bg4"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/bg5"
            android:layout_width="380dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.96" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_gender"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_gender"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.52"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bg5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/bg2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/bg5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bg5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/usergender"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Loading..."
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.52"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bg5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/bg5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/bg5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bg5"/>

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#9F9F9F"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I have tried using minHeight but it doesn't give me my desired result. I have also watch many tutorials on how to create a scrollable view but none have answered my question.

Comment: Please provide code as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12567365), not as screenshots. If you have not already done so, take a look at [ask] and try to [edit] your question to provide a [mre].

Comment: You can also read the guidance provided in [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) if this is a school assignment (but even if it isn't, the guidance is still worth reading).